# How to put matplot figures to one window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is my code where I get 3 different windows (3 figures):

```
nk.z_score(bio["df"][["Heart_Rate", "ECG_Filtered", "ECG_Signal_Quality"]])[5000:10000].plot()
pd.DataFrame(bio["ECG"]["Cardiac_Cycles"]).plot(legend=False)
ecg.ecg(signal=df["ECG"], sampling_rate=1000., show=True)

plt.show()
```

is it possible to layout them all together in one window?

**Clarification:**
I meant I've see how it's done in examples however I use `plot()` on pandas data frames or call it from different methods, not from created subplots (as in examples) and I wanted to know if I can put created from pandas dataframes plots together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subplots feature of matplotlib. Create multiple axes as per your data requirement and provide the axes instance as an argument for ax.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols)
df_1.plot(ax = ax1)
df_2.plot(ax = ax2)
```

Comment: @cnd please check the [subplots documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and [examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)